# restrict no of opportunity on account. account should have only 2 opty

Tags: apex, trigger

I have rollup summary field on account as no_of_opty__c.

my trigger is :

```
trigger resrictoppty on Opportunity (before insert) {

    for(opportunity opp :[select id,name, account.no_of_opty__c from opportunity where id in : trigger.new]){

        if(opp.account.no_of_opty__c >=2){

             opp.adderror('you cant add more opty this account');

        }

    }

}
```

it saved properly but not function as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trigger appears to be an overkill to me in this situation. I think a validation rule on the Account side should suffice your need. As mentioned in the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en&type=0)

> Salesforce prevents users from saving a record if it invalidates a related 
>   record. For example, a master record has a validation rule that requires the 
>   roll-up summary field value to be greater than 100. If the user’s change to a 
>   related child record would put the value over 100, the user can’t save the 
>   record.

**Screenshot**
For test purpose I created a Validation rule with the following criteria

`No_of_opps__c > 1`
then throw the error and below is the screenshot when I try to associate another opp to an account.

[image]

Comment: its work for.... thanx for such smart solution

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things which you're missing:

1. You are querying opportunity before insert by `Id`. You should know that Opportunity Id's are generated after insertion.

Instead you can query accounts associated with your opportunities and then compare their values.

You should try something like this:
You can **optimize below nested for loops using Map** or something.

```
trigger resrictoppty on Opportunity (before insert) {
    Set<String> actId = new Set<String>();
    for(opportunity opp:trigger.new) {
        actId.add(opp.AccountId);
    }
    List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT id,no_of_opty__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN actId AND no_of_oppty__c >= 2];
    for(opportunity opp :trigger.new){
        for(Account act:lstAccount) {
            if(opp.AccountId == act.Id && act.no_of_opty__c >= 2){

                 opp.adderror('you cant add more opty this account');

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use aggregate function and use no_of_oppty greater than equal to 2 in WHERE clause. Then you don't need to loop through in for loop. It improves optimization

Comment: @SantanuBoral Thanks for the suggestion. I've modified the WHERE clause, Could you elaborate on how to use aggregate function in this scenario or else directly edit it.

Comment: @SantanuBoral please can you write code how to use aggregate function in this scenario and solve this problem

Comment: @pravin answer written is already a solution. You can try implementing it or else wait for Santanu's reply.

Comment: trigger resrictoppty on Opportunity (after insert) {

       for(opportunity opp: trigger.new){
       
           aggregateresult result = [select count(no_of_opty__c)opty from account where id =:opp.accountid ];
           integer i = (integer)result.get('opty');
           if(i>=2){
                opp.adderror('you cant add more opportunity this account');
           }
 
   }

} done with this code..

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the conditions in Before Insert, where Opportunity record has not yet created.

So, Opportunity Id is invalid. Thats why those condition will not get satisfied.

Comment: i have change event to after but it gives error asError: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger resrictoppty caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: resrictoppty: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors: Trigger.resrictoppty: line 7, column 1

Answer (score 0):

this code below work for me

```
trigger resrictoppty on Opportunity (before insert) {

    set<id> accid = new set<id>();

    for(Opportunity  o1 :trigger.new){

        accid.add(o1.accountid);

    }

   for(account acc :[select id,no_of_opty__c from account where id in :accid]){
       for(opportunity opp: trigger.new){

           if((acc.id==opp.accountid) && acc.no_of_opty__c>=2){

               opp.adderror('you cant add more opportunity this account');


           }


       }


   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

below code also work fine 
thanx to all of you
trigger resrictoppty on Opportunity (after insert) {

```
   for(opportunity opp: trigger.new){

       aggregateresult result = [select count(no_of_opty__c)opty from account where id =:opp.accountid ];
       integer i = (integer)result.get('opty');
       if(i>=2){
            opp.adderror('you cant add more opportunity this account');
       }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work properly because you use wrong condition at line No.1 **(before insert)**.
Try below code:

```
    trigger OppoTrigger on Opportunity (After insert){
    List<Id> acIdList=new List<Id>();
    For(opportunity opp :Trigger.new){
       acIdList.add(opp.AccountId);
      }
    Map<Id,Account> accMap= new Map<Id,Account>([select id,no_of_opty__c from
     account where id=:acIdList]);
    List<Account> updateList=new List<Account>();
    For(Opportunity op:Trigger.new){
       If(op.AccountId !=null){
         Account ac=accMap.get(op.AccountId);
       If(ac.no_of_opty__c >=2){
         op.addError('you cant add more opty this account');
       }
       else{
         ac.no_of_opty__c=ac.no_of_opty__c+1;
         updateList.add(ac);
         }
       }
     }
      Update updateList;
  }
```

Regards,
Ajay